# Cannot locate an element when using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am trying to log in to a website by using Chrome and Selenium, however elements cannot be located. I tried:

1. using same code on other website, it works.
2. find all elements in page, but nothing can be found. `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')`

- python ver = 3.8.1
- selenium ver = 3.141.0
- no iframe impact

[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]

```py
    settings = Settings()
    opts = ChromeOptions()
    # 使用headless无界面浏览器模式
    # opts.add_argument('--headless')
    # opts.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    opts.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", settings.selenium_opts_excludeSwitches)
    opts.add_experimental_option("prefs", settings.selenium_opts_prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=opts)

    opts = ChromeOptions()
    # opts.headless = False

    driver.get('http://itdms01/otcs/llisapi.dll?func=LL.getlogin&NextURL=%2Fotcs%2Fllisapi%2Edll%3FRedirect%3D1')

    # time.sleep(1)

    input = driver.find_element_by_id('Username')
    input.send_keys(settings.login_name)
```

Execute log:

```
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 113.0.5672
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 113.0.5672
 
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 113.0.5672
[WDM] - Trying to download new driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/113.0.5672.63/chromedriver_win32.zip
[WDM] - Driver has been saved in cache [C:\Users\deche\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\113.0.5672.63]
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 113.0.5672
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 113.0.5672
 
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\deche\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\113.0.5672.63\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/decher_PC_google_drive/Documents/Git/WebCrawler/dmsCrawler/spider/spider_functions_v1.0.py", line 312, in <module>
    input = driver.find_element_by_id('Username')
  File "C:\Users\deche\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\deche\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\deche\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\deche\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="Username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.93)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more detailled answer i need to see the element you are trying to scrape in a browser dev tool.

But for what i see:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('')
```

Has the problem of always looking for CSS selectors

> {"method":"css selector"..

I suggest to use:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*/*[@Id='Username']')
```

For standard elements as inputs and buttons xpath is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reply.
I think the element can be found by selenium and my code.

However the element type is <class 'NoneType'> while I print out by type() function. Thus selenuim consider the element is an Object not a html element.

This site is located in the company's internal network. I try to save as to local file and the issue can be reproduce. the local files can be download by below link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fcfiwRCA1r1YyOwsZh3Sf6jxzxZRdCHY/view?usp=share_link

and below is my Python Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

try:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('plug-in\chromedriver.exe')
    # browser.get('http://itdms01/otcs/llisapi.dll?func=LL.getlogin&NextURL=%2Fotcs%2Fllisapi%2Edll%3FRedirect%3D1')
    browser.get('file:///C:/Users/deche/Downloads/Content%20Server%20Log-in.html')
    input = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="Username"]')
    for item in input:
        print(type(item))
finally:
    print('11')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).